# how copyToLocal and copyFromLocal work under the hood

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I just wanted to know how **copyToLocal** and **copyFromLocal** in hadoop work under the hood. Do they use **MapReduce**?. I wanted a complete architectural view. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java file can be found here:

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/CopyCommands.java

Answer (score 4):

This commands do not use MapReduce, they just recursively copy the contents from source path to destination path using java IO streams for local FS and hadoop IO streams for HDFS.